# How to unlock the bootloader of a bricked device if developers option is not enabled

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, fastboot

I have a soft bricked Xiaomi Redmi 2, it's stuck in a boot loop. I can go into fastboot mode though, and the devices is recognized by fastboot. But when I run the commandfor unlocking the bootloader, I get following error:

```
fastboot oem unlock
FAILED (remote: Token verification failed, reboot the device)
finished. total time: 0.005s
```

and

```
fastboot flashing unlock
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.002s
```

I think the reason is that the developer option and USB debugging was not enabled by default in the device. And since it's bricked and stuck in a boot-loop I can't enable it now. Is there any other way to unlock the bootloader (or revive the device in general)?

Comment: Are you sure the command is correct and should work for your device? Usually if the device is OEM locked fastboot shows a different error.

Comment: unbrick device with QPST in EDL mode first

Comment: https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/wt88047

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/use-qualcomm-flash-image-loader-qfil

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/use-xiaomi-mi-flash-tool

Comment: @Robert I accidentally pasted the same error twice, I've edited my question.

Comment: *"How to unlock bootloader on Xiaomi devices?*" - do a research